# How do I make a conditional with hasClass that prints a text depending on the content of another div tag?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, typescript, dom

For example if have:

```
<div>New York</div>
```

So I would like to print another div like this:

```
<div>Free Delivery</div>
```

How would I do that using JS?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this with simple js condtion:

add a class/id to to the element `<div id="country">New York</div>`

and in your script:

```
window.onload = () => {
  const country = document.querySelector('#country');
  const printdiv = '<div>Free Delivery</div>';

  if(country && country.textContent.trim() == 'New York'){
  document.querySelector('#country').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend',printdiv)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for answering, it did not work, it does not appear or <div>Free Delivery</div>
Code: https://i.imgur.com/yeQwtrj.png
Result: https://i.imgur.com/JL5Dfqc.png

Comment: move your script tag before the end of the body tag..
or you can use window.onload to process something when the page fully loads.

window.onload = () =>{
   const country = document.querySelector('#country');
   const printdiv = '<div>Free Delivery</div>';

   if(country && country.textContent.trim() == 'New York'){
     document.querySelector('#country').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend',printdiv)
   }
  }

Answer (score 0):

add id to element :

```
<div id="country">New York</div>
```

and then

```
let country = $('#country')

setInterval(()=>{
   if(country.text()=='New York'){
      // Your code
      // exemple 
      alert('Congratulations ! We Ship for Free for New York 
            Customers');
   }
},3000)
```

i hope it was useful

Comment: thank you very much for answering!!!, the code doesn't work for me, could you put it in jsFiddle?

Comment: I have tried again, I am using jquery 3.3.1
it doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: How could I make it remove a hidden class if the New York div class exists?

Comment: can u explain more

Comment: Yes of course.
What I want is that if there is a visitor who is in a specific city within my site, an ad appears saying that there is free shipping for that.
I only want the conditional for this because I already have the script that solves the capture of the visitor's city.

Comment: That's why I wanted that conditional. For example, if the script detects that you live in New York (which is a country that has free shipping), an ad should appear that says: Free shipping.

Comment: i updated it again take a look

Comment: What can I put to make it appear free shipping?
I know very little about JS, sorry!

Comment: i updated it again

Comment: This code doesn't really work.

Comment: I don't want an alert to appear, I would like an ad to appear in div format. I tried with that code but it doesn't really work.

Comment: show me part of ur code maybe i can help u

Comment: Yes, perfect:
https://i.imgur.com/xrNunzq.png

Comment: Result:
https://i.imgur.com/tycBX1Y.png

Comment: i'm sorry my wifi is broken last night , the problem is move script tag to the bottom of body